# Read bulk data from file (XML/Flat/CSV) and upload data in database

Tags: java, database, bulk

I need to read around 1 000 000 lines of data from a file and upload the data in the database using Java.
Below are the details of requirement and some of the solution I've already written:

1. Read data from a file (any format XML, flat file, CSV).
   Depending upon the file format initialize the class (using Factory pattern). For text files I am using BufferedReader and then add each object created e.g. employee in a list.
   Similarly for XML I am using SAXParser and same as above after reading data from one object it is added to a list.
2. But I don't think we can save or we should be saving 1 000 000 objects in a list. So I need to flush data into data base parallely as the file is being read and list reaches a certain size. This is where I am stuck. How should this be handled? Should I run a parallel Thread which would update data in database once list size reaches say 1000 and meanwhile the thread reading the file should be put on wait?
   DB can be any database Oracle/ MS access.

Below is the code which is reading text file:

```
public class FlatFileLoader implements Loader {

@Override
public List<Employee> readData(String path) {

    try {
        List<Employee> personList =  new ArrayList<Person>();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
          String line=null;

          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              Employee person = scanLine(line, DataConstants.DELIMITER);
              if(null != person)
              personList.add(person);

            }
          br.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println(e);
        }
    return null;
}

private Employee scanLine(String recordLine, String delim) {
    Employee person=null;
    List data= new ArrayList();
    StringTokenizer lineScanner = new StringTokenizer(recordLine, delim);
    while (lineScanner.hasMoreElements()) {
        String nextEle= (String) lineScanner.nextElement();
        if(nextEle.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRST_NAME")){
            break;
        }
        data.add(nextEle);

    }
    if(data.size() > 0){
        DataUtil.populatedata(data);
    }
    return person;
}

}
```

Method
`DataUtil.populatedata(data)`
creates `Employee` object.
So where should I put the call for updating data in DB?
Any suggestion for improving above code is also welcome.

Comment: **In your scanLine method, you are initializing variable person (of type Employee) to null, and without modifying it you are returning the same. Hence scanLine will always return null. You might want to fix that.

Comment: could you please post how you're creating Employee object inside DataUtil.populatedata(data)

Answer (score 0):

How you want to flush the data depends basically on how much memory you want to use, but flushing the data after loading 1000 objects or so is a good idea since you dont have to write to DB for every instance of Employee loaded, nor will 1000 objects take up much memory.

If you are using a parallel thread to flush the List of Employee objects, then take care of the thread synchronization issues: Thread t1 might not finish inserting its 1000 objects into db before you create thread t2 to insert the next 1000 objects. Thus two threads are now parallelly inserting objects into DB, because of which the ordering of the data in your input files (XML, text) might not be preserved in the DB.

My suggestion: keep it simple and make the reader wait while the data in being inserted into the DB. 1000000 objects is not that many anyways...

Insert the DB insertion code after personList.add(person):

```
....
    if(personList.size()>=1000){
        flushToDB(personList);
        personList.clear();
    }
....
```

meanwhile,

```
void flushtoDB(List<Employee> persons){
    for(Employee person:persons){
        //insert Employee object into DB
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But one question, when flush to DB is happening nothing would be read from file? i.e. br.line would just be on hold? or has it by this time read the whole file and Buffered it? Sorry if this question is too basic, have never worked on I/O before.

Comment: Yes, flushToDB() will hold the file reading operation. It will not have buffered the whole file - just a block of 1000 entries. after writing to DB those entries will be removed and reading from file will resume.

Comment: :An extension to this req, other than file data can also come through a Message queue.So, I am using factory pattern to decide the class to be instantiated as per the type of data coming.Once I've got my loader class which should be the consumer and have use QueueConnectionFactory to create the receiver and read the message which would be a person object and then use the DBupdate class to update it in DB. Do you have any suggestion in this approach. One confusion I have here is, should the consumer keep checking on the queue if any msg has come or would it be notified automatically?